# Changing a start up init.d script to use with new ubuntu

Tags: startup, upstart, init.d

This is my code. I would like to change it to use with new versions of ubuntu. The thing is ubuntu doesn't have chkconfig any more. Also I heard that new ubuntu uses upstart instead of init type start ups.
So how can I use this code to use with ubuntu 13.10?

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 99 01
# description: SoftEther VPN Server
DAEMON=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver
LOCK=/var/lock/subsys/vpnserver
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
case "$1" in
start)
$DAEMON start
touch $LOCK
;;
stop)
$DAEMON stop
rm $LOCK
;;
restart)
$DAEMON stop
sleep 3
$DAEMON start
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```